# Problem following detail of Szemeredi's original proof that sets of positive upper density have arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory

Here is a link to Szemeredi's original proof of Szemeredi's theorem: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa27/aa27132.pdf

I am stuck on Fact 6 (page 212) because I don't follow the "induction" argument that *X'* and *R* have non-empty intersection.

Many thanks for your help.

Paul Epstein

Comment: This question was also posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158097/problem-understanding-detail-on-szemeredis-theorem-on-arithmetic-progressions

Comment: As you can find out if you have a look at some discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting], posting the same question to several sites is discouraged. If you do it, you should wait some time before doing so and you should also provide the link to the question on the other site. See for example these posts on meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/questions-posted-on-math-se-and-other-se-sites, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/questions-asked-simultaneously-on-other-se-sites, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelin